# Printing long interger in python up to 10 digits

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to take two long input integers (up to 10 digits) separated by space and display there sum.

I took the input into a string which are separated by space and then split them. After that I type caste them to `int`.

```
print "Enter two numbers"
a = raw_input()
a.split(" ")
sum = int(a[0]) + int(a[2])
print "\r", sum
```

Here I am not able to print the sum if the numbers are of even two digits.

Comment: `a = raw_input().split(' ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ignored the return value of `str.split()`:

```
a.split(" ")
```

Assign that back to `a`:

```
a = a.split(" ")
```

Python strings are immutable, you cannot split the value of `a` in-place (let alone replace the type, splitting returns a list object rather than a new string).

Comment: I think immutability isn't really the issue here since the result of the operation is a list, not a string.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: right, but the expectation was that `a` would be mutated in-place.

Comment: Yes, that expectation was obviously wrong. But "mutating" means changing the contents of an object, not creating a different object and binding it to the same name. Using the term here might confuse the OP even more. Perhaps a link to [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder might be helpful (for later reading).